# Log Standard Events using nativescript-facebook

Tags: nativescript, nativescript-vue

I want to log a Standard Event in Facebook like Add To Cart or Purchase (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-events/getting-started-app-events-ios), how can I do it? Can you share an example?

I am currently doing

```
const facebook = require("nativescript-facebook")
facebook.logEvent("Purchase");
```

But it generates a Custom Event named Purchase not an Standard Event that's recognized by Facebook.

Thanks!

Comment: It can be a better question if you can add more details and code @Hans please try create a nativescript playground example